# How to unbind focusout event from an element

Tags: jquery

A peculiar problem.

The script does something on 'mousedown' then executes on either event 'keypress', 'focusout', 'keyup'.

The question is how do I kill two remaining events once one of them is executed.

I've tried `$(document).off()`, `$(this).off('focusout')`, and nothing works.

Any clues?

```
.on('mousedown', '.task-content', function() {
    // Make DIV Editable
})

.on('keypress', '.task-content', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        // Update DIV content to DB
    }
})

.on('focusout', '.task-content', function() {
    // Update DIV content to DB
})

.on('keyup', '.task-content', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
    // Return DIV to previous state
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you show the actual code you tried for canceling/unbinding the events?

Comment: @Mathletics / I've edited the code a bit (those work fine BTW - it would be a long code to post). What specifically happens is that once I hit 'Enter' (keypress, 13) // focusout is still 'listening' and can be executed as well. See I want two other processes to be killed once one of them is used.

Comment: I guess he wants to execute only 1 of the 3 handlers, the unbinding is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine, maybe you might point a wrong `selector`.

```
$('.task-content').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        // Update DIV content to DB
        alert("key press");
        $(this).off('focusout');
    }
})

$('.task-content').on('focusout', function () {
    // Update DIV content to DB
    alert("focus out ");
})
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHTax/1/).

Comment: Thanks for this. I just managed to do that, however I need to 'reuse' focusout once on 'mousedown' again. // In other words, it can't be killed for good.

Comment: @October Using delegate will rebind it.

Comment: Isn't delegate superseded by .on()?

Comment: @OctoberEleven Thanks for correcting my mistake, you can use .on()